# In EverQuest, what's a good class to team up with a Bard?

Tags: everquest

My friend and I are going to start playing EQ on the new progressive server soon, and he's going to play a Bard. I don't mind which class I play, all that matters is that we work together well as a team.

Which classes work well for playing alongside a bard, and why?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since I played EQ, so keep in mind this might be outdated.

Bards are jacks of all trades, so just about any class should be fine. It really depends on which direction you want to lead your pairing (Ranged DPS, Melee DPS, Kiting...). Myself, I'd choose a ranged heavy DPS class like a Wizard or a Necro, which would benefit from the Bard's increased mana regen and stay conveniently away from the mobs the bard kites.